# I've made a Newton's Cradle [using the P5.js framework], but there's an unexpected problem

Tags: p5.js

Everything works just fine but there's a weird stutter at the start of the program. I have no idea what's causing that. [Here's the link to the code](https://editor.p5js.org/RuskinWadia/sketches/vIlAKv0xT)

Comment: You are getting a lot of errors. On my browser, the stutter coincides with the time the errors are displayed. Could that be the reason?

Comment: I had not assigned a few variables any values because they were going to be calculated during the course of the program, which was giving those non-critical errors. The stutter was fixed once I just assigned zero as a value for all of them during declaration. That solved the problem ! Thank you ! @M.Herzkamp

Comment: If you figured out the answer to this question, please post the answer or consider deleting the question. Otherwise it shows up as still needing an answer.

Comment: I totally forgot about that. I'll do it right away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning all variables some initial values did the trick.